# There has been a signature failure Crash

Tags: windows-7

My thinkpad threw the blue screen of death  repeatedly and each time I booted it was very slow. I logged in to safe mode to delete some temporary files. When i rebooted it went to the lenovo recovery mode where it looked like it was not doing anything much. I waited for about 45 minutes and did not see any progress on the progress bar. So, rebooted it and then came the "there has been a signation failure error".

So I tried to boot it with the windows cd to see if I could repair it and it went up to the point of copying files after which it just hung going in a signature failure loop.

Now all i see when i start the system is there has been a signature Failure message.

Has anyone faced this situation before?

How do i restore windows 7? all i can access is the bios mode.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Due to the use of the incorrect word in places in your question, its hard to follow what actually happen or even determine what your question is.

Answer (score 0):

A quick [Google search for you error](https://www.google.ca/search?q=windows+there+has+been+a+signature+failure+error) shows there are many people with Lenovo's that run into this problem.

[The first link](http://www.terabyteunlimited.com/kb/article.php?id=553) has some good information:

> Certain IBM and Lenovo systems (e.g. those utilizing Rapid Restore) use a nonstandard MBR, which spans four sectors instead of one. These sectors, the partitioning layout, etc. are validated by a checksum. Restoring an image to the drive causes the checksum to fail, which then causes the system to hang or display the error message.

The Lenovo recovery mode will reset the computer to as it was out of the factory by replacing the HDD contents with a fresh image of Windows.  It seems you stopped it before it was done, so now you've only got a partially written image on the drive and the Master Boot Record (MBR) checksum is now failing.

You can try the fixes listed there, but I think it's because the image was only partly done writing, so those fixes probably won't fix anything.  You're best bet is probably to just start the Lenovo Recovery Mode again, and this time let it finish (expect it to take a few hours).

If this isn't an option (and may not be, now that your ran a Windows installer form DVD against it). then use you Windows Setup disk and remove ALL the partitions on the drive, then install windows fresh (from the disk).